# How to make keyboard open automatically in android without clicking on it

Tags: android, keyboard, react-native, autofocus

for me keyboard should open automatically without clicking on it,i have used react-navigation so autofocus is not working while going from one screen to other screen

**I tried this:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buildNameTextInput = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: '90%',
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity />
          <TextInput
            autoFocus={!!this.buildNameTextInput}
            ref={this.buildNameTextInput}
            style={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: '80%'}}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#8ee3ab',
  },
});
```

but if i use this its not working after going to next screen,
if any one have any solution plz post it,
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Reference to focus the text input this.refname.current.foicus()

Check below code

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

componentDidMount() {
  this.input.current.focus()
}
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: '90%',
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity />
          <TextInput
            ref={this.input}
            style={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: '80%'}}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: We can also use autofocus = {true} prop which is a default one in TextInput Tag